# Connecting 3080ti to PSU

Tags: power-supply, gpu

We have a custom built desktop with a Supermicro x9dai board, and an evga 1000g PSU.  It has 6 8 pin VGA slots.  PCIe 3.0 x16.

We also recently just bought a 3080ti, which has 2 8 pin plugs, and it came with two cables that are 8 pin to TWO six pin connectors.  So the card requires 2 8 pin connections from the PSU, and the cables split into FOUR six pins.  Is it safe to plug the 4 6 pin connectors into 4 of the 8 pin VGA plugs on the PSU, which obviously wouldn't fully consume all 8 of the pin connections?

I originally tried the cables from the previous GTX780, which were 2 8 pin to 8 pin connectors, with 2 pins removed for the 2x6 pin 780.  There's no signal to the monitor with the 3080 connected, and unfortunately no on board graphics to utilize.  The 780 works fine in the same slot.

So I guess my primary question is if I can try the four 6 pin connectors provided in the 8 pin VGA plugs on the PSU.

Secondarily, can I install both the 780 and 3080 in separate slots, power them both, and use the working 780 just to see what's going on via the monitor?

If anyone has any ideas about the lack of signal, that would be great also.  Unfortunately I can't preinstall drivers for it (to my knowledge), as the NVIDIA drivers can't be installed without the relevant hardware connected (says it detects nothing during installation), but I can't install with it connected because the monitor has no signal.

Comment: “Is it safe to plug the 4 6 pin connectors into 4 of the 8 pin VGA plugs on the PSU, which obviously wouldn't fully consume all 8 of the pin connections?” - Just use the adapters. You obviously have a modular power supply. Only the cables provided by the PSU manufacturer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I tried the original cables that came with the PSU (8 pin to 8 pin), which logically seemed to be a no brainer.  8 pin connectors on both the PSU and the GPU, straightforward connection.  Unfortunately there's no signal and I was wondering if this was a factor and should try the cables that came with the GPU (8 pin to dual 6 pin).  I can't think of any other causes for lack of signal.  I noticed the fans are not spinning on the GPU, though I believe some are heat activated, rather than perpetually spinning.

Comment: Here's the theory, you'll have to test it. 6-pin plugs can only carry 75w, 8-pin 150. The GPU *must* see 8 pins to sense it can draw 150w [or it will not start]; as the other end has 2x6-pin to the PSU, the PSU is being told each of those can supply half the power, 2x 75w. So (2x6 to 1x8)x2 should be fine. The extra pins are an additional earth & the sense pin.

Comment: Thanks very much for the feedback.  I'll give this a try, I just wanted to confirm what I believed to be safe, connecting a 6 pin connector to an 8 pin plug on the PSU.  It actually has 4 VGA 8 pin ports free, so I can use all 4 for the 4 six pins which convert to 2 8 pins on the GPU.  Hopefully that's it, but it doesn't explain why the direct 8 pin to 8 pin cables would have caused no signal (could be that's not the real isssue).

Comment: Is it possible to connect 2 GPUs via separate PCIe x16 slots, not in SLI configuration, just so I can use the working one to get a video signal and troubleshoot the 3080?  No onboard graphics, and the PSU does have the capability to support both.